# Регулярное выражение для хэш тегов на PHP и на русском языке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Ни как не могу составить/найти регулярное выражение на PHP, для получения всех хештегов из текста и на русском языке так же. То есть, не только латиницу, но учитывать и кириллические хештеги.

Благодарен за любые подсказки. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getHashtags($string) {  
    $hashtags= FALSE;  
    preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $string, $matches);  
    if ($matches) {
        $hashtagsArray = array_count_values($matches[0]);
        $hashtags = array_keys($hashtagsArray);
    }
    return $hashtags;
}
```

Учимся гуглить... Просто первая [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16609221)